# Enable/Disable Chrome Extension content script with browserAction

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a simple content script which applies some js/css to any Facebook pages. I want to toggle whether the content scripts are applied with the browserAction button but can't seem to find if it's possible to disable content scripts from a background script. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: You could use `sendMessage` to send a message from the background script to the content script. With `onMessage` in the content script, you could set/toggle a flag (boolean). You can then use this flag inside the content script to control its behavior.

Comment: @Titus: You can have the background-page handle the content-script injection.